# Does Properties.load() report invalid bytes

Tags: java, properties

Does the `Properties.load(InputStream)` method report invalid bytes in its input?

The API specification clearly says that the `InputStream` must encode text using the ISO 8859-1 (Latin-1) character encoding. That does not permit the byte values 0x81-0x9F. So it ought to throw an `IOException` (a `CharacterCodingException` would be ideal) if such bytes are present. But does it? And if not, how *does* it handle those invalid bytes?

Comment: *"That does not permit the byte values 0x00-0x1F or 0x7F-0x9F"* Where did you get this info? [The first 128 characters of ISO-8859-1 is the original ASCII character-set](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_entities.asp).

Comment: @m0skit0 So indicates the Wikipedia page http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1.

Comment: @m0skit0 The Wikipedia page must be wrong about 0x00-0x1F and 0x7F, if ISO 8859-1 is a super-set of US-ASCII. But what about 0x81-0x9F?

Comment: I've edited mu question to concentrate on 0x81-0x9F.

Comment: Wikipedia doesn't say it doesn't permit such byte values. It says: *" where the little-used C1 controls **are replaced** with additional characters including all the missing characters provided by ISO-8859-15"*.

Comment: The API says "the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding". The Wikipedia page says "ISO-8859-1 (**note the extra hyphen over ISO 8859-1**), a superset of ISO 8859-1, for use on the Internet. This map assigns the C0 and C1 control characters to the unassigned code values thus provides for 256 characters via every possible 8-bit value."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Despite the claims of the specification, the provided implementation treats those invalid bytes as if they were Unicode characters; bytes in the range 0x81-0x9F will be interpreted as C1 control characters. The [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7/jdk7-gate/jdk/file/e947a98ea3c1/src/share/classes/java/util/Properties.java) has this:

```
 //The line below is equivalent to calling a
 //ISO8859-1 decoder.
 c = (char) (0xff & inByteBuf[inOff++]);
```

Despite what the comment says, that is **not** equivalent to calling an ISO8859-1 decoder.

---

**Edit**

In fact, it is equivalent to calling an ISO-8859-1 (note the hyphen) decoder. So there are two possible interpretations:

- The provided implementation is buggy.
- The specification (API) documentation does not correctly describe the intent of the authors; it should say that the stream uses the ISO-8859-1 encoding.

Answer (score 1):

The Properties file specification says that the input stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1.  However, it does not specifically state that control characters (specified in ISO/IEC 6429, for example) are illegal.  (In fact, certain of them; e.g. the white space characters HT,CR,NL, patently *are* legal.)  And the spec doesn't say what should happen with any hypothetically illegal characters.

In fact, what actually happens is that the Property reader does a rough-and-reading mapping that maps the control codes in the 8-bit input stream to the corresponding control codes in Unicode.  Then the Property loader treats any control codes that don't have a specific meaning as plain old characters, and includes them as-is in the keys and values.  (You can read the code [here](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/Properties.java.html) ... if you are interested.

And in fact, if you look at the source code of the Java ISO 8859-1 decoder (e.g. [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/sun/nio/cs/ISO_8859_1.java)) you will see that the decoder maps 8-bit characters *in exactly the same way*.  In other words, the control characters are all treated as valid ISO 8859-1 characters ... according to the Java interpretation.  That interpretation also turns out to be the IANA preferred interpretation:

> "In 1992, the IANA registered the character map ISO_8859-1:1987, more commonly known by its preferred MIME name of ISO-8859-1 (note the extra hyphen over ISO 8859-1), a superset of ISO 8859-1, for use on the Internet. This map assigns the C0 and C1 control characters to the unassigned code values thus provides for 256 characters via every possible 8-bit value."

(Quoted from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1 as of 2013-03-29)

In short, "the internet"'s usage of the term "ISO 8859-1" does not exactly match the ISO/IEC 8859-1:1998 standard ... but the mismatch actually makes the standard more useful.

(And if you think Java / IANA are wrong, imagine how **painful** it would be if Java interpreted the ISO spec literally, and the decoder turned `'\t'`, `'\n'` and `'\r'` into unmapped characters!)

Comment: ISO 8859-1 does not permit some bytes values. ISO-8859-1 (note the hyphen) does; it is ISO 8859-1 supplemented with ISO/IEC 6429.

Comment: OK, I wasn't aware of that fine distinction.  But either way, the Properties class and the ISO_8859_1 class behave the way they behave, and there is zero chance that they will change.  In my experience, I doubt you could even persuade them to correct the javadoc.  (Submitting a patch to openjdk might work ...)